# How to convert a date using the langage of the device?

Tags: android

In my Android project, I have 3 variables (string) :

```
String day = "26";
String month = "03";
String year = "1989";
```

I would like to have a variable (String date) with the date format of the device (depending of the langage) like this :

- If the device is in french, date = "26/03/1989"
- If the device is in english (USA), date = "03/26/1989"
- etc

How can I do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join your strings into one like in this example (obviously you can omit the date)

```
    String dateString = "03/26/2012 11:49:00 AM";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
    Date convertedDate = new Date();
    try {
        convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(convertedDate);
```

Prints:

```
Mon Mar 26 11:49:00 EEST 2012
```

EDIT: This example doesn't show how to get the phone local date format

Comment: Thanks ! It's working !

Answer (score 0):

SimpleDateFormat already support that.

You can especify your desired Locale or get the default from the device.

Take a look at the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Hope this helps.